# Show Rails error message in Ajax alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Using Rails 3.2. I wonder how can we push the error from Rails to show in the Ajax alert. Here is my code:

```
# posts_controller.rb
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update_attributes(params[:name] => params[:value])
    render :nothing => true
  else
    render :text => @post.errors.full_messages[0], :status => :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

# _form.html.erb
$("#status_buttons button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<%= post_path(@trip) %>",
    data: { _method: 'PUT', name: this.name, value: this.value },
    error: function() {
      alert(" *****************Rails error message here**********************");
    }
  });
});
```

The conventional validation error message should appear in the `alert()`. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one way to determine is to pass at least 3 arguments to the callback function and checking the console (or an alert) for whatever argument passes the error.

```
error: function(a,b,c) {
  alert('a contains ' + a);
  alert('b contains ' + b);
  alert('c contains ' + c);
}
```

one of them should contain the error message :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { ...
```